# button react.js a seccion

Tags: html, css, html5, reactjs

buen dia tengo un poblema, necesito crear un button y que este button lo mande a una seccion de la pagina web, el button lo con un href y el id de la seccion, y me manda a la seccion pero bruscamente, yo quisiera hacerlo que se deslice suavemente hacia la seccion que tenga animacion

```
a className="li1" href="#Funcionamiento">Funcionamiento</a>
<div className="container _3" id="Funcionamiento">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo una posible solución a lo que comentas, sin embargo no estoy seguro de si es la que buscas así que espero te sirva, intenté quedarme lo más fiel posible a tu solución con el href para hacer el scroll.

Te dejaré dos opciones para hacerlo.

Opción 1: CSS  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GzMNNV

*Cabe resaltar que debe de tener un height determinado y un overflow para funcionar.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <a href="#funcionamiento">Funcionamiento</a>
   <!-- Más contenido-->
   <div id="funcionamiento"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 100vh; //para todo el viewport, esto puede cambiar claro.
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; // Esta es la clave!
}
```

scroll-behavior permite que el salto sea inmediato o que se vea una animación de scroll hasta el elemento deseado.

Te dejo además el soporte entre navegadores

[image: Soporte en Navegadores]

Opción 2: scrollIntoView();

Para esta opción no he probado del todo, pero debería de funcionar también. Lo importante aquí es que no es necesario tener un contenedor con altura predeterminada.

```
class Scrollable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.scrollHereRef = React.createRef();
  }

  goToSection = function() {
      this.scrollHereRef.scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'}); //aquí el block puede ser 'start' también.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div onClick={this.goToSection} className="scrollButton">Scroll</div>
        <div id="big"></div>
        <div ref={this.scrollHereRef}>Hola</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

No hagas caso a Classname e id's fue para hacer los estilos al hacer el primer codepen (donde creo que no me deja crear Refs por ser codepen) (por si quieres ver los estilos para no confundirte aquí está el codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzoBjB)

Y la compatibilidad del scrollIntoView() en los navegadores https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView

Comment: eso era lo que buscaba amigo, probrare la segunda, pero si esto era, muchas gracias